# Why does Apple close socket/TCP connection is case of error/invalid token while sending push notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I realized this problem today:

http://redth.codes/the-problem-with-apples-push-notification-ser/

Is there a technical explanation as to why it happens this way, or is it just that Apple is not developer friendly. They could have queued the notifications at their end, and have ignored invalid tokens on their server, allowing the batch of notifications to be successfully sent using the same connection. I could query for invalid tokens later, using the feedback service. An invalid token resulting in a closed connection, which in turn results in all the notifications after that not being sent, is somewhat a foolish implementation to me from a web developers perspective. Or may be since I am not into socket programming, therefore I am overlooking some obvious details. Can someone please help me understand this. If that's a limitation of sockets, then may be as suggested in the blog post, Apple should move over to HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered the same thing, since this behavior of the APNS server is very annoying, and makes the implementation of the server side much more challenging.

I believe the reason for this behavior is that the format of the notifications we send to Apple is binary.

Lets assume you are using the simple binary format to send two notifications (but the explanation can be easily expanded to the newer formats) :

`0  0 32 device-token1 payload-length1 payload1 0 0 32 device-token2 payload-length2 payload2`

Now, if device-token1 has a length of 32 bytes, and the only problem with it is that it's invalid (i.e. it doesn't match any device in the current push environment), Apple could skip to the next message as you would like.

However, if you are missing one of the constant bytes (command or payload length), or you pass a device token of incorrect length, or the length of your payload doesn't match the payload length you supplied, Apple will have no way of knowing where the next notification begins. Therefore they close the connection and expect you to re-send any valid messages that followed the invalid message.

Comment: I am not sure if that's the case. Is the length of the device token the only constraint? I have tried that on a batch of valid and invalid tokens (but all tokens were 64 chars, or 32 bytes in binary representation), and the notifications don't get delivered to valid tokens, whereas they get delivered if I put the valid one at the beginning of the batch. Thoughts? Is there a way to validate the tokens before I queue them, so that there is a guarantee that the TCP connection will not be closed (and the invalid ones will be ignored by Apple). I can always sanitize data - easier than retry.

Comment: @amit_saxena I think you misunderstood me. Apple will close the connection due to any type of invalid data, even if there are no problems with token length.

Comment: As for sanitazing the data, you can try to send notification to each token,  and try to read error response after each message,  with large enough timeout.  It would be slow,  but you'll discover all the invalid tokens.

Comment: in that case your explanation doesn't hold true as the payload length is correct, and Apple could have easily ignored the invalid tokens, instead of closing the connection. The question still stands, why does Apple do it this way?

Comment: @amit_saxena My explanation still makes sense, because if you send Apple an invalid message, they can't know for sure where the invalid message ends, and the next message starts (which is what I tried to explain in my answer). Therefore, instead of potentially processing a long stream of junk bytes while trying in vain to find the next valid message, they close the connection once they encounter any problem, and force you to send them valid data.

Comment: invalid message = incorrect payload length (or other check digits and payload length fields are incorrect, etc.), right? In the case I described, I don't think that the message format will be wrong, and it will amount to invalid message (as the token size is correct, and everything else will be in correct format), or is my understanding flawed here? Thanks for all the help so far! Just trying to understand it better.

Comment: @amit_saxena My point is that even if all your messages are formatted correctly, and the only problem is that some of them have invalid token (but with a valid 32 bytes length), Apple can't be sure that's the case, so they decided (or so I assume) never to try finding the next valid message once they find any invalid message.

Comment: My point is that Apple will get all the messages as they were sent, and can decipher individual notifications from that, as they were formatted correctly (not the same case which you described in the answer). Now they can ignore the invalid notifications, and send the correct ones. Or is my understanding flawed here. Thank you for your time! If you can spare some time, we can discuss this over chat at a time of your convenience.